# How to make Docxtemplater.js work on browser without any knowledge of Node/Browserify/npm and such?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I want to make [Docxtemplater.js](https://docxtemplater.com/) work on browser.

Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of these things as Node.js, Browserify.js, "npm", "bower", and that kind of thing that appear in all those nice and cool modern JS libraries. I want to learn about them, but in the future... Right now I just want to make this Docxtemplater.js work.

In the bottom of the page, they show how to do it with npm, but I don't want that, so I went to the [Quickstart In The Browser](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater#quickstart-in-the-browser). I must have done something wrong, because it is not working.

This is what I did:

- I created a file called `testpage.html` with the following content:

  ```
  <html><body>
  <script src="build/docxtemplater.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jszip-utils.js"></script>
  <script>
  var loadFile = function(url,callback) {
      JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
  }
  loadFile("examples/tagExample.docx", function(err, content) {
      if (err) { throw e };
      doc = new Docxtemplater(content);
      doc.setData({
          "first_name": "Hipp",
          "last_name": "Edgar",
          "phone": "0652455478",
          "description": "New Website"
      }); //set the templateVariables
      doc.render(); //apply them (replace all occurences of {first_name} by Hipp, ...)
      out=doc.getZip().generate({type:"blob"}); //Output the document using Data-URI
      saveAs(out,"output.docx");
  });
  </script>
  </body></html>
  ```
- I created a folder `build` and put the file `docxtemplater.js` there, downloaded from [here](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater-build/tree/master/build), specifically the raw file [docxtemplater.v2.1.3.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater-build/master/build/docxtemplater.v2.1.3.min.js) (of course I renamed it to `docxtemplater.js`).
- I created a folder `vendor` and put the files `FileSaver.min.js` and  `jszip-utils.js` there, both files taken from [here](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/tree/master/vendor).
- I created a folder `examples` and put the file `tagExample.docx` there, taken from [here](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/blob/master/examples/tagExample.docx).

**That is precisely what I did. I did not add any other files or folders, or anything.**

Then, I opened the file `testpage.html` with my Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7. With the console open, I get the following error message:

`ReferenceError: Docxtemplater is not defined` - on this line: `doc = new Docxtemplater(content);`

### What's wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the source. It's not exporting the object to the global environment.

Probably should [submit an issue](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/issues) to the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution: just replace `new Docxtemplater(content)` with `new Docxgen(content)`.

This happens only when [downloading the JS build directly from github](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater-build/tree/master/build), as I did.

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/issues/241) about it, and now this is [properly documented in Readme.md](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater#js-download):

> If you download the JS from there, you should use new Docxgen() instead of new Docxtemplater(), because I do not want to bring in a breaking change on a minor version change in the docxtemplater-build repository.

It seems that "Docxgen" was the old name of the library, now renamed to "Docxtemplater".